# Sorting Azure Mobile Services API

Tags: javascript, azure-mobile-services

I want to return a sorted table to a rest service, but only getting the last record, what am I doing wrong here? Ideally I would then want to limit the records returned, example top 100 ? Thank you

Rest: https://restname.azure-mobile.net/api/test

```
exports.get = function(request, response) {    
var collectionOfVotes = request.service.tables.getTable('Country');
collectionOfVotes.orderByDescending('countryname')
.read({ success: function(results) { 
    results.forEach(function(r) {
            response.send(r);
            //console.log(r);
        });
}});
```

};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling the method `response.send` for **every record returned by the query**. Since only one request was sent, only one of those responses will be returned. If you want to send all records back, you should send the results as they were passed to the `success` callback.

Also, you can limit the number of records returned by using the `take` method in the table / query object, as shown below.

```
exports.get = function(request, response) {    
    var collectionOfVotes = request.service.tables.getTable('Country');
    collectionOfVotes.orderByDescending('countryname').take(100)
        .read({
            success: function(results) {
                console.log('results: ', results);
                response.send(200, results);
            }
        });
};
```